# How can I get the line of the text where an XML tag is found in Python using bs4 or lxml?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have an XML document and I want to get the line at which the tag extracted by `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` is found. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For BeautifulSoup this attribute is stored in the [sourceline attribute](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py?start_revid=594#L1087) of the Tag class, and is being populated in the parsers [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/builder/_html5lib.py?start_revid=594#L158) and [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eleonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py?start_revid=594#L150).

For lxml this is also possible through the sourceline attribute. Here is an example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from lxml import etree
xml = '''
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
    </c>
  </b>
  <d>
  </d>
</a>
'''
root = etree.fromstring(xml)

for e in root.iter():
    print(e.tag, e.sourceline)
```

Output:

```
a 2
b 3
c 4
d 7
```

If you want to look at the implementation of the [sourceline method](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/e986a9c/src/lxml/etree.pyx#L1058) it's actually calling [xmlGetLineNo](https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/e986a9c/src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd#L359) which is a binding of [xmlGetLineNo](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/46837d47d59c7b8c9bd1d08a6a717a90a7f1ceb6/tree.c#L4667) from libxml2 that is a wrapper for [xmlGetLineNoInternal](https://github.com/GNOME/libxml2/blob/46837d47d59c7b8c9bd1d08a6a717a90a7f1ceb6/tree.c#L4617) (where the actual logic for this lives inside libxml2).

You can [find the line number of the closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47903639/827519) as well by checking how many line endings there are in the text representation of the subtree of that tag.

[xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) can [also be extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430270/827519) to provide the line numbers where the elements have been found by the parser (the parser being xmlparser from the module [xml.parsers.expat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyexpat.html) ).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function.

For example, if we have the following HTML:

```
html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Heading</h1>
<p>My paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>"""
```

and we want the find the line number for the `<h1>` tag (`<h1>My Heading</h1>`).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for (index, value) in enumerate(
    # Remove all the empty lines, so that they shouldn't be part of the line count
    (x for x in str(soup).splitlines() if x != ""),
    start=1,
):
    # Specify the tag you want to find
    # If the tag is found, it will return `1`, else `-1`
    if value.find("h1") == 1:
        print(f"Line: {index}.\t Found: '{value}' ")
        break
```

Output:

```
Line: 4.     Found: '<h1>My Heading</h1>'
```